# Using a Singleton in XAML - Possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, singleton

I've got a singleton class called NotificationScheduler. I really ever only may have one of these in my app. The Singleton pattern is realized through an "Instance" property and only accessing the instance via this property like this:

```
    private static NotificationScheduler _instance = null;
    public static NotificationScheduler Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new NotificationScheduler()); }
    }

    public NotificationScheduler()
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (_instance != null)
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "WARN: A second Instance of NotificationScheduler has been created");
#endif
        _instance = this;
        init();
    }
```

But I also have a reason for this to have to be created in XAML like this:

```
        <NotifyIcon:NotificationScheduler x:Key="NotificationScheudlerInstance"
                        IconSource="/Images\Icons/myicon.ico"
```

I'm aware that this doesn't use the Instance property! Is that even possible? If I access the instance in code like this, an instance is created two times of course:

```
NotificationScheduler.Instance.DoSomething();
NotificationScheduler n = (NotificationScheduler) FindResource("NotifyIcon");
n.DoSomething();
```

At the moment, my solution is to do the FindResource thing to create the instance through the XAML code, then everything works fine.

Question: Can I create a resource in XAML via accessing a static property?

Comment: Whenever I hear singleton, I go here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: Other than the answer below about .NET 4.5 and static. A possibility is to manage the singleton outside the class interface in a factory or IOC library supporting singleton.

Comment: @Rudi Yes, that's the post where some code we give interviewees to read comes from. But it has nothing to do with the problem ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just have a singleton property like in your first snippet, and reference it using `{x:Static NotifyIcon:NotificationScheduler.Instance}` in XAML?  If it's a singleton, it shouldn't need to be a scoped resource.

Comment: If that works it would be the ideal solution, and a gaping hole in my knowledge about WPF. Sounds like I have to try this ASAP.

Comment: This seems to be the best thing. So you cannot create a XAML instance by referencing a static property, but if you need to bind to a property of a singleton instance, you can use this to bind to it. Thanks! This will keep my code much cleaner. Oh, and it also works in .NET 4.0 (where I tested it.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create a singleton in XAML, why not create a control of which there can be many instances, but all of which reference a static or singleton object? I think this would probably be easier to manage over time.

Comment: This would work, but also pretty much seems like a hack. But if nothing more useful comes up, I tend to like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a static property in .Net 4.5; more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#static_properties)

Comment: You don't need a binding for a singleton because, by definition, the value will never change.  Better to just use `{x:Static}`.